# How to return a generic type from a nested class using a method in the main class

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have a class that defers data type until instantiation and I want to return a generic data type from a method in that class. My class is declared in the following manner:

```
public class myClass<T> {
    private class nestedClass {
        public T item;
        constructor...
    }  

    private nestedClass x;
}
```

and I want a method that will return "item" from an object of type nestedClass which is of a generic type. What I am looking for is a method that would of the following form:

```
public GenericDataType myMethod() {
    return nestedClass.item;
}
```

When I run my code, I get an error that says, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: myClass.myMethod()LmyClass$nestedClass;"
The code that brings about this error is:

```
myClass<Integer> x = new myClass<Integer>();
x.myMethod();
```

As it stands, myMethod() looks like this:

```
public <T> T myMethod() {
    nestedClass a = new nestedClass();
    return (T)a.item;
}
```

Comment: `myClass` would need a reference to the instance of `nestedClass` to access its contents, of course.

Comment: @Smutje I am sorry for not making it clear initially. I have a reference to an instance of nestedClass. I updated that in my original question. I am getting the error "no such method exists" when I attempt to run my current method.

Comment: Even if you can't post your actual code, you still need to post enough so that we get the gist of what you're trying to do.  Anything confidential is extremely unlikely to be relevant to your question, so you should be able to eliminate that and change identifier names as needed.  As it stands, your question is not answerable.

Comment: Where is `myMethod()` declared?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method should return a generic type T, like this:

```
public <T> T myMethod() {
    return (T)nestedClass.item;
}
```

Working full example:

```
public class MyOuterClass {

    MyInnerClass<Integer> myInnerClass;

    public MyOuterClass(){
        myInnerClass = new MyInnerClass<>();  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyOuterClass myOuterClass = new MyOuterClass();
        System.out.println((String)myOuterClass.myInnerClass.myMethod());
    }

    public class MyInnerClass<T> {    
        private class NestedClass {
              public String item = "It works!";
        }

        private final NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();

        public <T> T myMethod() {
             return (T)nestedClass.item; 
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
It works!
```

**Note:**

In your example `NestedClass.item` doesn't actually need to be type-cast since item is of type `T`, but in case you want to return a different variable that isn't of type `T` then the type-cast is needed.

After the variable is returned you can type-cast it back to whatever object/primitive it originally was.

Comment: Please stick to the Java Naming Convention, even if the OP didn't.

Comment: That's better. ;-)

Comment: When I run that code, I still get the NoSuchMethodError. I am not sure what is wrong. Thank you for all the help thus far

Comment: You must be referencing the method incorrectly. But without you posting the actual code we cannot help you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)